# Do identifier rules apply for operator overloading function?

Tags: c++

According to the C++ identifier naming rules:

> A valid identifier is a sequence of one or more letters, digits, or underscore characters (_) and must start either with a letter or underscore. Spaces, punctuation marks, and symbols cannot be part of an identifier.

But the name of a function for operator overloading can contain characters other than a letter, digit or underscore, like for example:

```
user_data_type operator+(const user_data_type & t) const;
```

Is this an exception to the the identifier naming rules or does function names used for operator overloading not considered as an identifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From §3.1

> A name is a use of an **identifier** (2.11), **operator-function-id** (13.5), literal-operator-id (13.5.8), conversion-function-
> id (12.3.2), or template-id (14.2) that denotes an entity or label (6.6.4, 6.1).

So, as you can see, there are rules for the *identifiers* (which are the variable/function names). But there are some exceptions, and operator overloading (*operator-function-id*) is one of them, which means different rules apply to them.

From §13.5:

> operator-function-id: **operator** *operator*
>
> *operator*: one of
>
> - new delete new[] delete[]
> - + - * / % ˆ & | ~
> - ! = < > += -= *= /= %=
> - ˆ= &= |= << >> >>= <<= == !=
> - <= >= && || ++ -- , ->* ->
> - ( ) [ ]

So, `operator+` is allowed, `operator-` also, basically `operator` + `any of the operators listed above`.

Comment: So basically the `operator-function-id` sequence is not(technically) an identifier, right?

Comment: @stackerjoe Correct, it can't be both :)

Answer (score 10):

`operator+` is not a normal identifier, it is an *operator-function-id* as defined in 13.5/1 in N4140. By definition, it consists of the word `operator` followed by an operator, the `+` in your example. By this rule, you can also write

```
operator +
```

or even

```
user_data_type
operator


+
(const user_data_type & t) const;
```

as again, `operator+` is not a normal identifier.

The rule you cite does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

[The GNU C reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Lexical-Elements) states that

> there are five types of tokens: keywords, identifiers, constants,
>   operators, and separators

thus operator is not an identifier.

```
user_data_type operator + (const user_data_type & t) const;/*
^^^^^          ^^^^^    ^
identifier     keyword  operator
*/
```

Comment: Note that what applies to C might not apply to C++. So this doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: @Hiura you're right. For example C++ also has a valid symbol `~`. But in terms of the question my answer seems to be valid although it describes functionality from one language in terms of another.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overload functions can only contain punctuation or symbols that are operators which can be overloaded. When using the keyword `operator` followed by a valid operator you are using a built-in feature of C rather than creating your own identifier.